# Matlab - reading in a variable and every 15 time steps and setting the that variable equal to the value read in for the following 15 time steps

Tags: matlab, variables, time

I'm working with Matlab but have run into a problem when trying to assign a variable a certain value over numerous iterations.

The primary time step is set to 60 seconds, however, I need to read in a variable, temperature, from an external program. This is to be done every 15 minutes, and it is impossible to read it in every 60 seconds to match the simulation time step.

Is there anyway to assign the value read in to the temperature variable for 15 time steps until the next value is read in?

I was working with something along the lines of:

```
for ii = 2:M-1

  temperature(2) = 20;
  .
  .
  .
  temperature(14) = 20;

  for ii = 15:15:M-1
    temperature(ii) = (read in value)
  end

  Main Code(which uses the temperature value)

end
```

Comment: Your approach is fine. If you want to duplicate some data a certain number of times quickly have a look at the `repmat` function.

Comment: It is easy to solve with `mod` function. Just use `if mod(ii-2,15)==0` instead of your second loop. THis should work just fine (not sure about the -2 because I didn't check your code but just the question)

Comment: I would recommend to edit your post:1.) the tag [tag:time] isn't right because your loop step beeing time is irrelevant. You are not using time-specific analysis.  2.) Your code should be marked as code (mark the whole code and press ctrl+k.    3.) your title is quite of long and unspecific. You could shorten it to e.g.: `Changing a variable inside a loop only each 15th itteration step`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this solution should work. I have no Idea what your "real" program is doing so its still kind of abstract. If you got any questions feel free to comment.

```
l=0; %variable for your Temperature (here Temperature1)
for k=2:1:600
    if mod(k-2,15)==0 %using k-2 because your loop starts with 2. You could also use k if you predefine tmp_Temperature as Temperature1(1)
        l=l+1;
        tmp_Temperature = Temperature1(l);
    end
    Here is your code with tmp_Temperature beeing your Temperature

end
```